# \troy\ImageUpload\ImageUpload onComplete возвращает строку, а не объект

Tags: php, yii2

В Yii2 возвращаю ответ в виде JSON.

Если посмотреть ответ с помощью AJAX, то ответом возвращается объект. Все замечательно.

```js
$.ajax({
   url: // ссылка на контроллер и действие,
   type: "GET",
   success: function(data) {
     // Здесь data - это объект. 
   }
});
```

Если же ждать ответа от \troy\ImageUpload\ImageUpload, то тут другая картина.

```js
'onComplete' => new JsExpression("
  function(fileName, responseJSON) {
    alert(responseJSON); // Здесь не объект, а строка. Причем строка такая <pre>{JSON:JSON}</pre>
  }
```

Как правильно прочитать ответ от \troy\ImageUpload\ImageUpload?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В config указать `'responseType' => 'json'`

```
<?= \troy\ImageUpload\ImageUpload::widget(
    [
        'targetId' => 'imageUpload',
        'config' => [
            'action' => Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['u/upload']),
            'responseType' => 'json',

        ]
    ]
); ?>
```